# Querying iOS Keychain using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm stuck converting the Keychain query result using Swift.

My request seems to be working:

```
let queryAttributes = NSDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, "MyService",     "MyAccount",       true],
                                   forKeys: [kSecClass,                kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecReturnData])


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    var dataTypeRef : Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttributes, &dataTypeRef);

    let retrievedData : NSData = dataTypeRef!.takeRetainedValue() as NSData
    *** ^^^^can't compile this line^^^^
})
```

My problem is, code won't compile:

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %114 = bitcast %objc_object* %113 to %PSs9AnyObject_, !dbg !487
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %115 = bitcast %PSs9AnyObject_ %114 to i8*, !dbg !487
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

I don't know how to convert `Unmanaged<AnyObject>` to `NSData`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also trying to get access to the iOS Keychain and I saw your post.  I can't figure out how to get the query dictionary created.  I even copied your first line above into my application and it says the same thing.  "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments".  Have I missed something?

Comment: Same issue with latest XCode as of 3/11/2015

Comment: If you're looking for a simple drop-in keychain wrapper, you could try this one:

http://github.com/ashleymills/Keychain.swift

Answer (score 18):

Use `withUnsafeMutablePointer` function and `UnsafeMutablePointer` struct to retrieving the data, such as the following:

```
var result: AnyObject?
var status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&result) { SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttributes, UnsafeMutablePointer($0)) }

if status == errSecSuccess {
    if let data = result as NSData? {
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine with release (Fastest [-O]) build.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me when releasing the application (other solutions worked well in xcode, but not when distributing the app in a beta release).

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The others won't work in a release build.

Comment: You're a star, kishikawa. Unfortunately cannot use your wrapper as it requires 8.0, but that sorts me out.

Comment: In my case, this was also the only workable solution in a release build. Also, I'd love to know why other implementation won't work in release build.

Comment: +1 This worked for me too. Thank you so much! The other method only worked on iPhone 5S+. On the iPhone 5- it would crash.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you have hit a compiler bug, which you should report. You can take a different path to retrieving the value, such as the following:

```
    var dataTypeRef :Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttributes, &dataTypeRef);

    let opaque = dataTypeRef?.toOpaque()

    if let op = opaque? {
        let retrievedData = Unmanaged<NSData>.fromOpaque(op).takeUnretainedValue()

    }
```

The error manifests itself when using `AnyObject` as a type parameter `T` of `Unmanaged<T>`. The following code snippet compiles without issue, which uses a more specific type, `CFError`:

```
    let url = NSURL(string:"dummy")
    var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let succeeded = CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(url, .Process, &errorRef)

    if errorRef {
        let error = errorRef!.takeRetainedValue()
    }
```

As the Keychain API returns a different result depending of the query attributes, the use of `AnyObject` is required.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I'll report it then and maybe wait to see if fixed in next beta. If not, I'll use this code. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like this is working when you set the Swift Compiler - Optimization Level to -Onone. But when you set it to -O. Opaque will be nil.
Build with Xcode 6.1(6A1052d)

Comment: I'm getting a bad access exception on the line `let opaque = dataTypeRef?.toOpaque()` (Xcode 6.1 & 6.2b)

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work you need to access the retained value for each keychain constant first.  For example:

```
let kSecClassValue = kSecClass.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecAttrAccountValue = kSecAttrAccount.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecValueDataValue = kSecValueData.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecClassGenericPasswordValue = kSecClassGenericPassword.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecAttrServiceValue = kSecAttrService.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecMatchLimitValue = kSecMatchLimit.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecReturnDataValue = kSecReturnData.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
let kSecMatchLimitOneValue = kSecMatchLimitOne.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
```

You'll then need to reference the constant you created in the keychain dictionary object like so.

```
var keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPasswordValue, service, userAccount, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecMatchLimitOneValue], forKeys: [kSecClassValue, kSecAttrServiceValue, kSecAttrAccountValue, kSecReturnDataValue, kSecMatchLimitValue])
```

I wrote a blog post about it at: http://rshelby.com/2014/08/using-swift-to-save-and-query-ios-keychain-in-xcode-beta-4/

Hope this helps!

rshelby