# SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags() in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-foundation, security-framework

I am trying to call a function in the Security.framework, from swift code. Forgetting about the "error out" (last) parameter for a second, if I call the function like this:

```
let accessControlRef = SecAccessControlCreateFlags(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
            SecAccessControlCreateFlags.UserPresence,
            nil
        )
```

I ge tht efollowing error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'SecAccessControlCreateFlags' that
>   accepts an argument list of type '(CFAllocator!, CFStringRef,
>   SecAccessControlCreateFlags, nil)'

...however, if I reformat my code to the following:

```
let allocator:CFAllocatorRef! = kCFAllocatorDefault

let protection:AnyObject!     = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly

let flags:SecAccessControlCreateFlags = SecAccessControlCreateFlags.UserPresence


let accessControlRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
    allocator,
    protection,
    flags,
    nil
)
```

(specific types -e.g., `CFAllocatorRef`- taken from function prototype on Xcode's autocomplete)...it compiles with no problem. **What's going on?**

Next, **the error parameter**. What should I pass? Migrating my Objective-C code, I am tempted to pass the following variable (prepended with `&`, of course):

```
var accessControlError:CFErrorRef! = nil
```

...which gives the error:

> Cannot invoke 'SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags' with an argument list
>   of type '(CFAllocatorRef!, AnyObject!, SecAccessControlCreateFlags,
>   inout CFErrorRef!)'

If, instead, I pass the following variable (again, prepended with the address-of operator):

```
var accessControlError:UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>
```

(Same type as suggested by prototype autocomplete), I get:

> Cannot invoke 'SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags' with an argument list
>   of type '(CFAllocatorRef!, AnyObject!, SecAccessControlCreateFlags,
>   inout UnsafeMutablePointer?>)'

**...so, what gives?**

**EDIT:** Forget about the error parameter. I seems I am taking the address twice (i.e., pointer to a pointer). Instead, I should do this:

```
var accessControlError:UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?> = nil
// ^ Already a 'pointer'

let allocator:CFAllocatorRef!         = kCFAllocatorDefault
let protection:AnyObject!             = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly
let flags:SecAccessControlCreateFlags = SecAccessControlCreateFlags.UserPresence 

let accessControlRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
        allocator,
        protection,
        flags,
        accessControlError // <- Notice the lack of '&'
)
```

Source: sample code within [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24197966/433373).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(OK, so nobody has added any new insights in a while, so I will answer my own question with the contents of my last edit:)

**ANSWER:** Forget about the error parameter. I seems I am taking the address twice (i.e., pointer to a pointer). Instead, I should do this:

```
let accessControlError:UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?> = nil
// ^ Already a 'pointer'

let allocator:CFAllocator!         = kCFAllocatorDefault
let protection:AnyObject!             = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly
let flags:SecAccessControlCreateFlags = SecAccessControlCreateFlags.userPresence 

let accessControlRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
        allocator,
        protection,
        flags,
        accessControlError // <- Notice the lack of '&'
)
```

Comment: FWIW, you can also use, "var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>?" and pass a reference "&error" Ref: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/706/